# How to catch HTTPS errors in $('<img/>').onLoad()

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, exception, https

I try to maintain a strict "clean error log" policy in my web pages, for my own sanity as well as for end-users' confidence in the page.

**Is there a way to trap HTTP errors when loading remote content into a page element?**

My code looks like this :

```
/*   Vew validation rule added to jQuery Validation */
$.validator.addMethod(
      "remoteImage"  // This is the name of the new rule, applied to 'val_ImageURL' below.
    , function (url, element) {
        $('#divImageURLresult').removeClass("invalid").removeClass("validated"); // Clear previous simulated validation results
        $('<img/>').attr('src', url).on("load", function() {
           $('#editImageHeight').val(this.height);
           $('#editImageWidth').val(this.width);
           $('#divImageURLresult').html("Height : " + this.height + ". Width : " + this.width);
          $('#divImageURLresult').addClass("validated");  // Simulated validation result
        }).error(function() { 
           $('#editImageHeight').val("Unknown"); // Force validation to fail. Height can only be a number.
           $('#divImageURLresult').html("Not an image.");
           $('#divImageURLresult').addClass("invalid");  // Simulated validation result
        });
        return true;  // Always return true since we get here before the image load callback returns.
      }
    , "");
```

---

### Example bad value log :

> The page at
>   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RI5j_aIBipv3En8s/edit#gid=7042'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from
>   'http://i.imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig': this content should also be loaded
>   over HTTPS.
>
> GET http://imgur.com/Xgng8S9.pig 404 (Not Found)

---

There is no way to NOT use HTTPS for Google HTMLService pages. but there is also no way to ensure users will only load HTTPS pages.

I should handle those types of error internally, it seems to me.  How do I do it?

Also, is the "... but displayed insecure content ..." message enforced to be available to the end-user?

Comment: Check if the image `src` is `https` before you load it.  Then you know before loading if the error will appear.  If you do proceed to load it, as far as I know there is no way to suppress Chrome's error message.  (At a stretch, you could try listening for `error` events on the `window` and doing `event.preventDefault()` but I'm not overly hopeful that will prevent them from appearing in the log.)